# How to get old Coldfusion MX7 Serial Number In FileSystem

Tags: coldfusion, serial-number, coldfusion-7

In production, I had two ColdFusion MX7 Server. One crashed last month and I would retrieve my Serial Number to reinstall my environment.

I know that it's possible to get back the Serial number from the Administrator interface but I can't start my server. I'm just able to have access to the File System.

Is it possible to retrieve the Serial number of the crashed machine from the File System without using the Administrator Interface? If it's possible, where could I find it in my "CFusionMX7" root directory?

Comment: this refers to CF 8 but might also apply CF7: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1154153

Comment: Hi, Great ! It's works ! I found my file in "ColdFusionRootDirectory\lib\license.properties". Thanks

Comment: cool, I'll add some of the details as an answer in case it'll help anyone else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Details from this forum discussion here:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1154153

Find the `[cf_root]\lib\license.properties` file.  The serial number is on the line beginning `sn=`